# Java Convert MultipartFile to File for large files

Tags: java, spring, multipart

I'm using the below method to convert MultipartFile to a File:

```
public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
}
```

Which works fine but for large files I got this exception:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I added more heap, but I'm still having the error.

So is there a programmatic way to fix this maybe splitting the multipart file to smaller chunks while converting, but I'm not sure how to code it.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `file.getInputStream()` will return the stream,will it helpful to you?

Comment: MulipartFile should have a `toFile(file)` method for this.

Comment: `new File(file.getOriginalFilename())`. Mmm what happens if two simultaneous requests upload "untitled.pdf" at the same time? All kinds of bad things, I suppose. Plus, malicious users will have a field day. I'd personnaly love to try "C:\Win32\whatever" or "~/bash.rc" as example names (DONT DO THIS! NEVER EVER trust user submitted content)

Comment: @GPI actually we will never heve 2 files with the same name as I append the time at the end of the file like this: "untitled-09-10-2018-hh-mm-ss-ms.pdf"

Comment: OK that's good to know... But you still have a user generated prefix path ? That can be dangerous. And what if the user file name contains "/" or ":" or "\" ? I would treat the user generated name as metadata (or drop it altogether if not necessary), and generate a unique, FS-safe name (e.g. `Files.createXXXFile` family of methods).

Comment: Yeah I didn't think about that, I'm also thinking of renaming the file using a hash function, thanks btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `MultipartFile` belong to Spring's package `org.springframework.web.multipart`? If so, you could do

```
  public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
    convFile.createNewFile();
      try(InputStream is = file.getInputStream()) {
        Files.copy(is, convFile.toPath()); 
      }
    return convFile;
  }
```

Comment: it show this error cannot resolve method 'copy(java.io.InputStream, java.io.FileOutputStream) on this line Files.copy(...)

Comment: Stream will not be closed in case of an exception. try-with-resources should be used here (`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile)`).

Comment: I don't know where you took `Files.copy(InputStream, OutputStream)` from, but the input stream should probably be closed properly as well (but that depends on the library).

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb it's a mistake probably and the OP meant either [`IOUtils#copy`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) from Apache Commons IO or Guava's [`ByteStreams#copy`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-).

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Updated my answer. @jannis `Files.copy(InputStream, OutputStream)` is actually a private method of `java.nio.file.Files` class. My mistake

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb `Files.readAllBytes()` reads all bytes into memory and potentially causes OOME. You should try to read from stream instead.

Comment: You have an error in `Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), convFile.toPath())`. Should be `Files.copy(is, convFile.toPath())`. Otherwise you open two streams and leave one hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will help you to divide File in chunk of and then you have to aggregate

```
try
        {
            file = new File(filePath.toString());
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            checksum = getFileCheckSum(messageDigest, file);
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            int fileSize = (int) file.length();
            fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
            int numberOfChunks = (int) Math.ceil(fileChannel.size() / (double) chunkSize);
            int totalpacket = numberOfChunks;
            int totalFileSize = fileSize;
            int read = 0;

            while (numberOfChunks > 0)
            {

                System.out.println("file is :" + file + "checksum is:" + checksum);
                fileSize -= read;

                if (numberOfChunks > 1)
                {
                    ByteBuffer bytebuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(chunkSize);
                    read = fileChannel.read(bytebuffer);
                    bytebuffer.flip();
                    String content = new String();
                    if (bytebuffer.hasRemaining())
                    {
                        content = new String(bytebuffer.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                    }


                    bytebuffer.clear();

                }
                else
                {

                    String chunkData = new String();
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(fileSize);
                    fileChannel.read(byteBuffer);
                    chunkData = new String(byteBuffer.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                    byteBuffer.clear();
                }

                numberOfChunks--;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            log.info(e);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae)
        {
            log.info(nsae);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                fileInputStream.close();
                fileChannel.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                log.info(ioe);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using transferTo:

```
public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
 {
  File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
  file.transferTo(convFile);
  return convFile;
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't save the file I got FileNotFoundException

Comment: Sorry then you have to add a create statement first.

Comment: what do you mean by create statement ?

Comment: public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
 {
  File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
  convFile.createNewFile();
  file.transferTo(convFile);
  return convFile;
}

Comment: I checked the api and the createNewFile is not helpful. Looks like the point might be your environment - are you running with servlet 3.x api?